# Query data on hierarchy model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

I have a form on which the users can find the contact information about their coworkers by name.

This is my form:

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
```

My model is as follows:

```
Person: idPerson, fname, lname, bdate, mail
Employee: idEmp, hireDate, idPosition, mailCorp, idPerson
```

I want to find employees by name (contained in fname or lname) and show the name and mailCorp, How can I obtain this with Linq and how can I show this in the view. (I use EF)

I try to do something like this but it doesn't work

Controller

```
public ActionResult searchOnDirectory(Person per)
{
    var query = from p in Person
                join e in Employee
                where e.Employee.fname.Contains(per.name)
                select new {p.fname, p.lname, e.mailCorp};
    return View(model);  // I don't know how to send the select result
}
```

View

```
@foreach (var per in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <!--<td></td>-->
        <td>@per.fname @per.lname</td>
        <td> @per.Employee.mailCorp </td>
    </tr>
}
```

PD: sorry for mistakes, I have to translate all my code because I speak spanish

Comment: Are you going to leave us to guess what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's not understood? :/

Comment: Show us your code - what you have tried.

Comment: Provide the full models, or at least the models with the relevant properties and clearly explain what outcome you need

Comment: `doesn't work` - Can you explain what does it mean? Do you see any errors or a picture of horse or does it run away from you?  Your code contains properties that you haven't mentioned in the property list at the top, What is `e.Employee`? What is the type of `param`?

Comment: I'm not sure how make the query in order to obtain the result that I explained

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I think this is what you are trying to get at, you are missing an `on` in your query.

```
 var query = from p in Person
                join e in Employee                     
                on p.idPerson equals e.idPerson
                where p.idPerson equals per.Name
                select new {p.fname, p.lname, e.mailCorp};
```

If you are simply looking up the person based on an id why not just query against that?